# Remover um ITEM de um ARRAY com CLICK

Tags: javascript, array, button

Eu estava num projeto pessoal para treinamento, fazendo uma lista de supermercado, adicionando items, valor e somando os valores, porém queria adicionar um botão para excluir tal produto com click, não consigo, tive a dicar de usar o methodo filter(), mas nada da cérto

```
var items = [];

document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    
    var nomeProduto = document.querySelector('input[name=nome_produto]');
    var precoProduto = document.querySelector('input[name=price]');

    items.push({
        nome: nomeProduto.value,
        valor: precoProduto.value
    });

    let listaProdutos = document.querySelector('.lista-produtos');
    let soma = 0;
    listaProdutos.innerHTML = "";
    
    items.map(function(val){
        soma+=parseFloat(val.valor);
        listaProdutos.innerHTML+=`
        <div class="lista-produto-single">
        <h3>`+val.nome+`</h3>
        <h3 class="price-produto"><span>R$`+val.valor+`</span></h3>
        <button name="remove">X</button>
   </div>
        `;
    })
        
    soma = soma.toFixed(2);
    nomeProduto.value = "";
    precoProduto.value = "";

    let elementoSoma = document.querySelector('.soma-produto h1');
    elementoSoma.innerHTML = 'R$'+soma;   
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Se tiveres o indíce do produto podes usar a função splice().

```
var items = [];

document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    
    var nomeProduto = document.querySelector('input[name=nome_produto]');
    var precoProduto = document.querySelector('input[name=price]');

    items.push({
        nome: nomeProduto.value,
        valor: precoProduto.value
    });

    mostrarProdutos();
});

function mostrarProdutos() {
    let listaProdutos = document.querySelector('.lista-produtos');
    let soma = 0;
    listaProdutos.innerHTML = "";
    let i = 0;
    
    items.map(function(val){
        soma+=parseFloat(val.valor);
        listaProdutos.innerHTML+=`
        <div class="lista-produto-single">
        <h3>`+val.nome+`</h3>
        <h3 class="price-produto"><span>R$`+val.valor+`</span></h3>
        <button value=`+i+` class="remove">X</button>
   </div>
        `;
        i++;
    });
    eventoRemover();

    soma = soma.toFixed(2);
    nomeProduto.value = "";
    precoProduto.value = "";

    let elementoSoma = document.querySelector('.soma-produto h1');
    elementoSoma.innerHTML = 'R$'+soma;   
}

function eventoRemover() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".remove").forEach(function (element, id) {
        element.addEventListener('click', function() {
            items.splice(element.value, 1);
            mostrarProdutos();
        });
    });
}
```